# How use react components from npm in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, npm, summernote

I am new in react and I follow this article https://www.airpair.com/reactjs/posts/reactjs-a-guide-for-rails-developers
 to use react in rails app and everything was fine. But later I wanted include in `records.html` page [summernote](http://summernote.org/) (WYSIWYG html editor). I found this npm module [react-summernote](https://github.com/Vnkitaev/react-summernote) and can't make editor works.

This is my code (try 1):

- application.js

```
var ReactSummernote= window.ReactSummernote = global.ReactSummernote = require('react-summernote');
```

- index.html.erb

```
<%= react_component 'ReactSummernote'%>
```

This is my code (try 2):

- summernote.js.coffee

```
@RichTextEditor = React.createClass
  render: ->
    React.createElement ReactSummernote
```

- index.html.erb

```
<%= react_component 'RichTextEditor'%>
```

and got this error

> react.self-e3251ec….js?body=1:1285 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Constructor`.

Answer (score 2):

Some things worth checking;

I'm assuming your node packages are being installed to `/node_modules/*`.  Make sure those packages are being added to your asset pipeline.  I've used [browserify](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails) to accomplish this.

Check in your browser console to see if the variable is being set (just type `ReactSummernote`.  The result should be a function if it is imported correctly, or undefined if there is some problem).

If you've gotten this far and are still stuck, I would recommend triggering the render without using react-rails.  It's easy enough to render the component onload of your page through vanilla javascript, and if it's the react-rails gem that is causing you problems, this will navigate around it easily with something like this;

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Comment: thank you so much for this: "Check in your browser console to see if the variable is being set (just type ReactSummernote. The result should be a function if it is imported correctly, or undefined if there is some problem)."